# KQL - Searching in lists/strings

Tags: kql, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

I'm setting up an Azure workbook that allows VM's to be selected using a parameter that I have called `virtual_machines`. When I select multiple VM resources using this parameter, it behaves in a query as below (I'm just using :names)

```
print ('{virtual_machines:names}')

vm-test-01, vm-test-02
```

I'm now trying to use this in a query but I'm getting no results. I think it's struggling with the fact the values aren't quoted individually. For example, if I use it in my usual `where` clause I get no results.

```
| where Computer in ('{virtual_machines:names}')

The query returned no results.
```

Should I be using a different method to filter other than `in` or should I be manipulating my `{virtual_machines:names}` list somehow? I'm new to KQL and am a little confused by the data types I'm dealing with here in terms of lists, dictionaries etc...

Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: How did you set the parameter (there are various option for this)? What do you mean by "I'm just using :names"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-value parameter

[image: Multi-value parameter]

```
print Computer = "vm_test_01"
| where Computer in (dynamic([{virtual_machines_names}]))
```